# Why do Python's frameworks return dictionaries from controllers?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, web2py

Why (for example web2py) do you return data from a controller in a dictionary instead of variables (see Rails)?

For example:

```
return dict(sape=4139, guido=4127, jack=4098)
```

instead of (that's the way Rails does it)

```
@var1 = "jello" 
@var2 = "hihi"
```

Is there any advantage using dictionaries over plain variables (speed-wise/code-wise)?

Update: The above way is actually a correct way for creating a dictionary (at least in Python 2.6.1). The other way (that many people say it's the correct one)

```
return {"var1": "jello", "var2": "hihi"}
```

is not used a lot by python frameworks.

From [Python's documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html):
"When the keys are simple strings, it is sometimes easier to specify pairs using keyword arguments:"

```
dict(sape=4139, guido=4127, jack=4098)
```

Comment: that's not a dictionary you're returning. That's not a standard/valid data structure in python.

Comment: yeah sorry. I confused ruby with python syntax :D

Comment: that still a syntaxerror

Comment: hm, where is the syntax error? I am missing smth?

Comment: Check here about how web2py returns dictionaries. http://mdp.cti.depaul.edu/AlterEgo/default/show/106

Comment: -1: Please correct the code, var1 should be "var1" in the dict, and why the @? Or are you just trying to write Ruby code in Python?

Comment: @nikow: @var1 is an example in Ruby.

Comment: @Jon: dict doesn't work with square brackets.

Comment: @SilentGhost -> I think that's the way web2py wants it.
Check from the link I posted before:  
return dict(form=form,rows=rows)

Comment: Check the python documentation guys:
"When the keys are simple strings, it is sometimes easier to specify pairs using keyword arguments:
dict(sape=4139, guido=4127, jack=4098)"

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: @Jon: square brackets are not the same as parentheses.

Comment: @SilentGhost: I know, I was talking about the later versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main advantage is that this is the only way in python to return a) more than a single value **and** b) give that value a name. Other options would be to use a class (extra code), return a tuple (no names, so you'd have to use indexes to access the values) or allow to return only a single value which would probably mean that everyone would return a dictionary since that's the most simple solution.

It also allows to wrap several methods and join/merge their results. Lastly, it allows to return different sets of value/name pairs for each call easily, for example, omit optional values or return additional hints.

Comment: In Python 2.6+ `collections.namedtuple` allows both to return multiple values and to give names to these values.

Comment: So, why in rails the @variable is chosen to export variables to views? Why the same approach is not followed by other python frameworks?

Comment: I don't know about rails but maybe they try to prevent to leak internal information (which is why most frameworks don't use local()). As for other frameworks: I know that TurboGears and web2py use this approach. From my point of view, that's "all". Dunno about Django.

Comment: Or maybe the Rails syntax would make this approach "ugly".

Answer (score 3):

You can use local variables if you'd like:

```
def hello():
    var1 = "whatever you like"
    var2 = "another value"
    return locals() # or vars()
```

`hello.html`:

```
<html><body>
 <p>var1 {{=var1}}</p>
 <p>var2 {{=var2}}</p>
</body></html>
```

[from PHP to web2py](http://mdp.cti.depaul.edu/AlterEgo/default/show/106):

> In web2py an HTTP request for
>   "/app/c/f" is mapped into a call to
>   the function f() in file (controller)
>   c.py in the application "app". The
>   file c.py is written in Python. The
>   output of the function f() can be a
>   string (in this case it is returned),
>   or a set of variables (implemented as
>   a python dictionary). In the latter
>   case the variables are rendered into
>   HTML by a file c/f.html, called a
>   view.

Comment: Not really a recommended approach, though, as it's an easy way to end up passing data to your templates that you never intended to pass.

Comment: @Carl Meyer: I agree. Explicit dictionary is better.

Comment: for small functions like that I would just return locals() to same space

Answer (score -1):

The nice thing is that a template engine like Jinja2 treats an object and a dict similarly, so if:

```
d = {'color': 'red'}
o = Color(red)
```

then these all work in the template syntax:

```
d.color d['color'] o.color o['color']
```